# MYSQL Stored Procedure - Concat Row Value

Tags: mysql, if-statement, select, stored-procedures, window-functions

***Update***

Sorry for the delay in responding. I was traveling yesterday when I sent that in. I am on version 5.6. This is what I was thinking of and it does mark when there is change, but the  issue is the sort causes the result set to fall out of order. I guess I will need to create a temporary table and just apply the conditional formatting once the order has been set.

SET @previousstate = '';

SELECT
    frm.fi_details.PortfolioCode AS 'Portfolio Code', id,
    if(@previousstate != frm.fi_details.PortfolioCode, concat('***',@previousstate:= frm.fi_details.PortfolioCode,'****'), frm.fi_details.PortfolioCode) AS test

FROM
    frm.fi_details

WHERE
    frm.fi_details.manager = 'Shartz' And
    frm.fi_details.PortfolioCode Like ('Brown%')

GROUP BY
    frm.fi_details.PortfolioCode,
    frm.fi_details.Symbol

ORDER BY
    frm.fi_details.PortfolioCode,
    frm.fi_details.WorstDate_Final;

brownfmi    143753  brownfmi

brownfmi    143748  brownfmi

brownfmi    143744  brownfmi

brownfmi    143739  brownfmi

brownfmi    143740  brownfmi

brownfmi    143738  brownfmi

brownfmi    143747  brownfmi

brownfmi    143749  brownfmi

brownfmi    143761  brownfmi

brownhcb    143769  brownhcb

brownhcb    143774  brownhcb

brownhcb    143780  brownhcb

brownhcb    143781  brownhcb

brownhcb    143773  brownhcb

brownhcb    143784  brownhcb

brownhcb    143783  brownhcb

brownhcb    143785  brownhcb

brownhcb    143786  brownhcb

brownhcb    143762  ****brownhcb****

brownhcb    143763  brownhcb
brownhcb    143788  brownhcb
brownhcb    143777  brownhcb
brownhcb    143767  brownhcb
brownhcb    143764  brownhcb
brownhcb    143779  brownhcb
brownhcb    143778  brownhcb
brownhcb    143789  brownhcb
brownhcb    143772  brownhcb
brownhfi    143799  brownhfi
brownhfi    143808  brownhfi
brownhfi    143805  brownhfi
brownhfi    143806  brownhfi
brownhfi    143793  brownhfi
brownhfi    143795  brownhfi
brownhfi    143797  brownhfi
brownhfi    143791  brownhfi
brownhfi    143801  brownhfi
brownhfi    143807  brownhfi
brownhfi    143798  brownhfi
brownhfi    143804  brownhfi
brownhfi    143796  brownhfi
brownhfi    143790  **brownhfi**
brownhfi    143800  brownhfi
brownhfi    143794  brownhfi
brownhfi    143802  brownhfi
brownhfi    143792  brownhfi
brownhfi    143803  brownhfi
brownira    143809  **brownira**
browntrf    143838  browntrf
browntrf    143860  browntrf
browntrf    143905  browntrf
browntrf    143891  browntrf
browntrf    143846  browntrf
browntrf    143877  browntrf
browntrf    143857  browntrf
browntrf    143872  browntrf
browntrf    143834  browntrf
browntrf    143898  browntrf
browntrf    143841  browntrf
browntrf    143817  browntrf
browntrf    143826  browntrf
browntrf    143822  browntrf
browntrf    143868  browntrf
browntrf    143883  browntrf
browntrf    143899  browntrf
browntrf    143840  browntrf
browntrf    143900  browntrf
browntrf    143850  browntrf
browntrf    143869  browntrf
browntrf    143865  browntrf
browntrf    143837  browntrf
browntrf    143844  browntrf
browntrf    143851  browntrf
browntrf    143901  browntrf
browntrf    143833  browntrf
browntrf    143856  browntrf
browntrf    143870  browntrf
browntrf    143875  browntrf
browntrf    143887  browntrf
browntrf    143903  browntrf
browntrf    143828  browntrf
browntrf    143847  browntrf
browntrf    143820  browntrf
browntrf    143890  browntrf
browntrf    143889  browntrf
browntrf    143867  browntrf
browntrf    143866  browntrf
browntrf    143830  browntrf
browntrf    143896  browntrf
browntrf    143836  browntrf
browntrf    143852  browntrf
browntrf    143876  browntrf
browntrf    143904  browntrf
browntrf    143874  browntrf
browntrf    143813  browntrf
browntrf    143854  browntrf
browntrf    143815  browntrf
browntrf    143878  browntrf
browntrf    143842  browntrf
browntrf    143897  browntrf
browntrf    143863  browntrf
browntrf    143879  browntrf
browntrf    143880  browntrf
browntrf    143849  browntrf
browntrf    143816  browntrf
browntrf    143862  browntrf
browntrf    143858  browntrf
browntrf    143831  browntrf
browntrf    143832  browntrf
browntrf    143835  browntrf
browntrf    143873  browntrf
browntrf    143848  browntrf
browntrf    143839  browntrf
browntrf    143827  browntrf
browntrf    143864  browntrf
browntrf    143823  browntrf
browntrf    143895  browntrf
browntrf    143884  browntrf
browntrf    143871  browntrf
browntrf    143810  **browntrf**
browntrf    143824  browntrf
browntrf    143821  browntrf
browntrf    143812  browntrf
browntrf    143892  browntrf
browntrf    143881  browntrf
browntrf    143861  browntrf
browntrf    143829  browntrf
browntrf    143819  browntrf
browntrf    143811  browntrf
browntrf    143894  browntrf
browntrf    143818  browntrf
browntrf    143882  browntrf
browntrf    143843  browntrf
browntrf    143859  browntrf
browntrf    143855  browntrf
browntrf    143885  browntrf
browntrf    143902  browntrf
browntrf    143893  browntrf
browntrf    143886  browntrf
browntrf    143845  browntrf
browntrf    143825  browntrf
browntrf    143888  browntrf
browntrf    143853  browntrf
browntrf    143814  browntrf

---

For some reason, I am having trouble thinking through how I would contact a row if it is different than the previous in a stored procedure. For example if I select states from my table, when the select gets to a new state have it append '**' to make it stand out. I know I have to set a variable and if else through it, but everything I tried has failed. :(

Thanks for your help.

**For example**

**AR**

AR

AR

AR

**CA**

CA

CA

CA

Comment: Please show us your current code.

Comment: Does the row have an ID column(s) or can you add one? Usual trick is to join the table to itself by ID to ID+1, then update the state where row1 state not equal to row2 state.

Answer (score 0):

You have not shown your existing code, so it is unclear how your question relates to stored procedure. If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can do this a `select` statement and window functions. To get a *consistent* result over consecutive executions, you would need a column that defines the ordering of the rows - I assumed `id`:

```
select
    id,
    case when row_number() over(partition by state order by id) = 1
        then concat('**', state, '**')
        else state
    end
from mytable
order by state, id
```