# MYSQL Stored Procedure - Concat Row Value (continued)

Tags: mysql

***Update / Answer***
To fix this issue, I added the keyword BINARY to each side of the comparison operator. This generated the expected results. Also note that I set the variable to empty string. Setting this to NULL did not resolve the issue.

```
SET @previousstate = '';
SELECT  
if(**BINARY** @previousstate != **BINARY** frm.fi_details_temp.PortfolioCode,
```

***End Update / Answer***

This is somewhat related to [MYSQL Stored Procedure - Concat Row Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62416667/mysql-stored-procedure-concat-row-value). That thread was based on Mysql 5.7.

The following statement worked under MySQL 5.7. I am in the process of trying to get it to work in MySql 8. I had to update the SET statement to 'SET @previousstate = NULL;' otherwise I get "Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '<>'". This error was way above my understanding. I am just a marketing guy working in a small firm. So that is why I set it to NULL.

With that said, after updating the SET statement the result set returns but the if() statement is not working like it did under 5.7. The very first row returned should have the first column of data marked with '*' at the beginning and end, and as the data in the column changes it should mark it too.

So it should look like this:

```
*brownfdn*
brownfdn
*brownfmi*
brownfmi
```

But I am getting this:

```
brownfdn
brownfdn
brownfmi
brownfmi
```

Do you have any thoughts about what I am doing wrong? I appreciate your help!! Getting to MySql 8 has been a struggle.

***5.7***

```
CREATE table fi_details_temp AS (
SELECT
    frm.fi_details.PortfolioCode,
    frm.fi_details.MaturityDate_Final
From
    frm.fi_details
Where
    frm.fi_details.manager = 'Bartz' And
    frm.fi_details.PortfolioCode Like ('Crown%')
Group By
frm.fi_details.PortfolioCode,
frm.fi_details.MaturityDate_Final

Order By
    frm.fi_details.PortfolioCode;
 
SET @previousstate = '';

SELECT  
if(@previousstate != frm.fi_details_temp.PortfolioCode, concat('*',@previousstate:= frm.fi_details_temp.PortfolioCode,'*'), frm.fi_details_temp.PortfolioCode) as 'Portfolio Code',
    frm.fi_details_temp.MaturityDate_Final as 'Maturity Date'
From    frm.fi_details_temp;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS fi_details_temp;
END
```

*** Create Statements - the above was a trimmed down version ***

```
CREATE TABLE `fi_details` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `RecordDate` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `PortfolioCode` varchar(8) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `manager` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `RunDate` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `RunDate_Final` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `AsOfDate` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `AsOfDate_Final` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Symbol` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Coupon` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `MaturityDate` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `MaturityDate_Final` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `ParValue` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `MarketValue` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `AdjustedUnitCost` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `TotalAdjustedCost` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `SPRating` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `MoodyRating` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `YieldCost` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `YieldMarket` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `YieldCall` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `YieldPut` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `YieldWorst` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `WorstDate` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `WorstDate_Final` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `CallDate` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `CallDate_Final` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `CallPrice` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `PutDate` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `PutDate_Final` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `PutPrice` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `FirstCouponDate` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `FirstCouponDate_Final` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `LastCouponDate` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `LastCouponDate_Final` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Freq` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `BondCalendarCode` char(1) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `SecTypeCode` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Security` varchar(80) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_fi_details_MaturityDate_Final` (`MaturityDate_Final`),
  KEY `idx_fi_details_PortfolioCode` (`PortfolioCode`),
  KEY `idx_fi_details_PortfolioCode_MaturityDate_Final` (`PortfolioCode`,`MaturityDate_Final`),
  KEY `idx_fi_details_manager_MaturityDate_Final` (`manager`,`MaturityDate_Final`),
  KEY `idx_fi_details_MaturityDate_Final_manager` (`MaturityDate_Final`,`manager`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=234850 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `fi_details_Worst_Date_Hartz_Brown`()
BEGIN
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS fi_details_temp;
CREATE table fi_details_temp AS (
SELECT
    frm.fi_details.PortfolioCode,
    frm.fi_details.MaturityDate_Final,
    frm.fi_details.YieldWorst,
    frm.fi_details.WorstDate_Final,
    frm.fi_details.YieldMarket,
    frm.fi_details.Symbol,
    frm.fi_details.Security,
    frm.fi_details.Coupon,
    frm.fi_details.ParValue,
    frm.fi_details.MarketValue,
    frm.fi_details.TotalAdjustedCost,
    frm.fi_details.AdjustedUnitCost,
    frm.fi_details.YieldCost,
    frm.fi_details.YieldCall,
    frm.fi_details.YieldPut,
    frm.fi_details.CallDate_Final
From
    frm.fi_details
Where
    frm.fi_details.manager = 'Hartz' And
    frm.fi_details.PortfolioCode Like ('Brown%')
Group By
frm.fi_details.PortfolioCode,
    frm.fi_details.MaturityDate_Final,
    frm.fi_details.YieldWorst,
    frm.fi_details.WorstDate_Final,
    frm.fi_details.YieldMarket,
    frm.fi_details.Symbol,
    frm.fi_details.Security,
    frm.fi_details.Coupon,
    frm.fi_details.ParValue,
    frm.fi_details.MarketValue,
    frm.fi_details.TotalAdjustedCost,
    frm.fi_details.AdjustedUnitCost,
    frm.fi_details.YieldCost,
    frm.fi_details.YieldCall,
    frm.fi_details.YieldPut,
    frm.fi_details.CallDate_Final
Order By
    frm.fi_details.PortfolioCode,
    frm.fi_details.WorstDate_Final );
 
SET @previousstate = NULL;
SELECT  
if(@previousstate != frm.fi_details_temp.PortfolioCode, concat('*',@previousstate:= frm.fi_details_temp.PortfolioCode,'*'), frm.fi_details_temp.PortfolioCode) as 'Portfolio Code',
    frm.fi_details_temp.MaturityDate_Final as 'Maturity Date',
    frm.fi_details_temp.YieldWorst as 'Worst Yield',
    frm.fi_details_temp.WorstDate_Final as 'Worst Date',
    frm.fi_details_temp.YieldMarket as 'Yield to Market',
    frm.fi_details_temp.Symbol,
    frm.fi_details_temp.Security as 'Description',
    frm.fi_details_temp.Coupon,
    frm.fi_details_temp.ParValue as 'Par Value',
    frm.fi_details_temp.MarketValue as 'Market Value xAI',
    frm.fi_details_temp.TotalAdjustedCost as 'Adjusted Cost',
    frm.fi_details_temp.AdjustedUnitCost as 'Unit Adjusted Cost',
    frm.fi_details_temp.YieldCost as 'Yield to Cost',
    frm.fi_details_temp.YieldCall as 'Yield to Call',
    frm.fi_details_temp.YieldPut as 'Yield to Put',
    frm.fi_details_temp.CallDate_Final as 'Next Call Date'
From    frm.fi_details_temp;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS fi_details_temp;
END
```

Comment: Please post the task itself: source data sample (as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts, or create a fiddle) and desired output. *I am in the process of trying to get it to work in MySql 8.* You must drop everything built for 5.7 and solve the task from the same beginning.

Comment: Hi Akina, sorry for the delay. I have added the additional information. Thank you for your help.